# Rounder corners in UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics

i have a UIView and i would like to round it and add shadow color like this image : [image: image rounded]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Rounder Corner

```
 CAShapeLayer * maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: self.bounds byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii: (CGSize){10.0, 10.}].CGPath;

    self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

For Shadow

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-15, 20);
self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: thanks for your answers, the rounders corners works fine but not the shadow. it's not working like the image. Thanks

Comment: Also note that clipping and shadows like this can often cause performance issues when used in scrollviews or during animations. If you encounter this, you can alleviate the problem by rasterizing the layer with `self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;`

Answer (score 0):

To get the very same shadow as your image I would recommend you using a background image. Otherwise you should include `<Quartzcore/Quartzcore.h>` and use the following code:

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
view.frame = CGRectMake(15, 15, 100, 100);
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0);
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
view.layer.shadowRadius = 10;
```

**Some more information for the background image-option**

Create a UIView that has the same width and height as the image including the shadow and assign the image to it this way:

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundview.png"]];
```